# How can I use a Custom jQuery file in folder using a template php file to generate output?

Tags: php, jquery

I have an html file that I want to use as a template. I wanted to have a separate folder for each company, (about a dozen?), and have a custom jQuery file in each folder.  I want to be able to send the company a link such as “http://websiteurl/companyname” that would bring them to a customized page for their company.

I was thinking that the best method would be to put the customized jquery file in each directory, along with an identical html file that would include the template html file.

I have the code pasted below.

The question is:
Why is it not implementing the include file? Can an included file in a different folder, be used like I am using it
Is there a more effective way to do this? I am not great with jQuery.

The code for the identical file inside of the folder would be:

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to company1 page!</h1>
<?php
require (__DIR__ . '/s/template/indextest.php');
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

The code in the include file is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Local News, news, local" />
<meta name="rights" content="test“/>
<meta name="description" content="Local news by Locals" />
<title>Calendar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/hhlibraries/css/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.custom.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/include/css/hh-calendar.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/hhlibraries/css/random_article.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/hhlibraries/css/random_article.css" type="text/css" />

<style type="text/css">

h1, h2 { font-family: 'Questrial', 'Helvetica', arial, serif; }
</style>
<script src="/hhlibraries/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/hhlibraries/js/jquery/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/hhlibraries/js/jquery/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/hhlibraries/js/jquery/jquery.csv.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script src="jquery.csvmain.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)
[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-
analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-22514165-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');



</script>
</head>
<body  class="logo-type-afterburner2 headerstyle-hhcolor menustyle-light footerstyle-dark font-family-questrial font-size-is-default menu-type-dropdownmenu layout-mode-responsive col12 option-com-dpcalendar menu-home ">
<header id="rt-top-surround">
<div id="rt-header">
    <div class="rt-container">
        <div class="rt-grid-4 rt-alpha">
```

....

Comment: I do not fully understand your question but you probably want to use include or require statements http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I doubt you actually want to create folders. That could be a nightmare to maintain as your number of companies increase over time.  A better approach might be to parse the url on request for the company name then applied the template and database info to produce the appropriate html page to push back out in response.

Comment: what you need is php. not jquery. same as hawkings comment

Comment: I left out the include statement in the original post, I apologize. The above code shows the statement  "Welcome to company1 page" but does not include the php file - nothing else appears on the screen. If I load the included php file through the browser, the correct web page appears.